# Bootstrap modal doesn't displays

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

The demo is here: http://obuh.by/test/lime/

The problem is when I try to display the modal on button «Показать», it appears and disappears immediately.

Comment: can u post some code ....preferably in jsfiddle

Comment: The demo is here: http://obuh.by/test/lime/

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of button from `submit` to `button`, right now you submit the form and page reloads:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#requestModal" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-main btn-warning">Показать</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. but I changed button to: `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#requestModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-main btn-warning">Показать</a>` and disables the bootstrap.js and only in this case it begin to work